# jtable.setModel gives java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have a jbutton which loads data from a DB, and then populates a jtable (using a DefaultTableModel)

Then, I have this event on the row selection of the table:

```
jTableDettagliFattura.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
                    int selected= jTableDettagliFattura.getSelectedRow();
                    String id = jTableDettagliFattura.getModel().getValueAt(selected, 0).toString();
                    System.out.println(id);
                }
            });
```

When I load the table for the first time (using the button), everything works fine. But if I select one of the table rows, and then reload the table with the button, I get the "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1", at the command "jTableDettagliFattura.setModel(model);" (that was perfectly working the first time).

What could be the problem?
Is the selection event somehow "ruining" my model?

Comment: Try `if (event.getValueIsAdjusting()) return` as the first line

Comment: What do you mean? I don't get that "return" you suggested...

Comment: Did you actually do what I suggested?

Comment: I tried, but i get a compile error. What do you mean with "as the first line"? Before "int selected= jTableDettagliFattura.getSelectedRow();"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if I select one of the table rows, and then reload the table with the button, I get the "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1"

There is no row selected when the model is reloaded. The listener probably fires an event to indicate the selection was removed.

Try:

```
int selected = jTableDettagliFattura.getSelectedRow();

if (selected == -1) return;
```

The main point is don't assume a row is selected. Validate the index before doing your processing.

Comment: Yes, i can't remember now whether that's exactly equivalent

Comment: It worked, but i don't get why. I mean: if no row is selected, why should i get an error when i try to apply the model to the table? The first time that I load the data, when the table is empty, I don't get that error...

Comment: Ok I read it. But I probably don't get the message you are trying to tell me... Have I done something wrong?

Comment: @Maik When someone answers your question and solves the problem you should "accept" the answer to indicate the problem is solved. I'm not sure why you need to be reminded, you have "accepted" answers in the past.

Comment: I don't know... you gave a concrete solution, but as i said in the comment here above, in my eyes it makes no sense that the problem doens't show up at the first table load. Do you understand why? Could you please try to explain it to me?

Comment: I did explain it to you. The selection changed. In your first case there is no selection when the table is loaded. So when you click on an item you get a proper index. When you change the model nothing is selected by default so when the selection is removed so you get a -1 index. If you need more help then post a proper [mre] that demonstrates the problem. We can't tell you exactly what happens since we don't have the exact logic flow. We can only make assumptions. An MRE should be included with every question. Only then can we attempt to give a complete accurate answer.

Comment: Ok I probably understand: when i load the data the second time, the emptying of the table is an event somehow catched by the listener, but at that point the selection index is -1